# Crash when all number from array are checked and printed

Tags: jquery

Im trying to create this thing where function randomly selects a value from array, then prints it out and store it into **#kaytetyt**.

It will also check if number is already found in #kaytetyt, if that is true then it will try again until it finds brand new number.

Problem is when it reaches the array length limit which is nine in this case. Browser will crash. How to prevent this? Also when all numbers are in use it could say "All numbers are in use". If you have some ideas how to improve code please do share, thanks ;)

```
var testi = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];

$(function() {

$("#arvo").click(function() {

    var koodi = testi[Math.floor(Math.random() * testi.length)];

    if ($('#kaytetyt > pre:contains(' + koodi + ')').length > 0) {

        $("#console").append("<pre class='red'>" + koodi + " is used, randoming new one</pre>");

        do {
            koodi = testi[Math.floor(Math.random() * testi.length)];
        } while ($('#kaytetyt > pre:contains(' + koodi + ')').length > 0);

        $("#kaytetyt").append("<pre class='new'>" + koodi + "<pre>");
        $("#console").append("<pre class='new'>" + koodi + "</pre>");

    } else {
        $("#console").append("<pre>" + koodi + "</pre>");
        $("#kaytetyt").append("<pre>" + koodi + "</pre>");
    }
});

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jaakkouu/4et38ktj/10/

Comment: You need to check if all your available numbers have already been used.  Without looking too closely, something like: `if ($('#kaytetyt > pre').length >= testi.length) { alert("all done"); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, for that works good.

```
$(function() {

$("#arvo").click(function() {

    var koodi = randomIntFromInterval(1,9);

    if ($('#kaytetyt > pre:contains(' + koodi + ')').length > 0) {

        $("#console").append("<pre class='red'>" + koodi + " is used, randoming new one</pre>");

        do {
            koodi = randomIntFromInterval(1,9);
        } while ($('#kaytetyt > pre:contains(' + koodi + ')').length > 9);

        $("#kaytetyt").append("<pre class='new'>" + koodi + "<pre>");
        $("#console").append("<pre class='new'>" + koodi + "</pre>");

    } else {
        $("#console").append("<pre>" + koodi + "</pre>");
        $("#kaytetyt").append("<pre>" + koodi + "</pre>");
    }
});

function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

});
```

Comment: This still prints out the numbers even thou all numbers been through.

Comment: This is another things, but the crash problem has gone, right ?